# spring-security compilation error

Tags: spring, spring-security, gradle

I'm trying to compile spring-security 3.2.0 using Gradle.  I'm getting an error with the spring4-tests.

I'm running the compile using:

```
gradlew clean build -x javadoc
```

Here is what is displayed in my DOS prompt:

> 609 tests completed, 1 failed :spring-security-config:spring4Test
>   FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':spring-security-config:spring4Test'.
>
>   > There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/spring/spring-security
>   >     -3.2.0.RELEASE/config/build/reports/spring4-tests/index.html
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4 mins 21.298 secs

How do I resolve the error?

Here is my Gradle info:

> ### ------------------------------------------------------------ Gradle 1.10-rc-2
>
> Build time:   2013-12-11 10:54:54 UTC Build number: none Revision:
>   36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6
>
> Groovy:       1.8.6 Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2
>   compiled on July 8 2013 Ivy:          2.2.0 JVM:          1.7.0
>   (Oracle Corporation 21.0-b17) OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64

Here is what is in the report referenced above:

Failed tests
http/openid-login/attribute-exchange

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain()
>   throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.BaseSpringSpec.loadConfig(BaseSpringSpec.groovy:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.NamespaceHttpOpenIDLoginTests.http/openid-login/attribute-exchange(NamespaceHttpOpenIDLoginTests.groovy:79)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain()
>   throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
>     at
>   java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:387)
>     at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:114)
>     at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:72)     at
>   java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:56)  at
>   java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1150)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:433)   at
>   java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:174)    at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.NamespaceHttpOpenIDLoginTests$OpenIDLoginAttributeExchangeConfig.configure(NamespaceHttpOpenIDLoginTests.groovy:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:369)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:322)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:326)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
>     ... 15 more

Comment: No attempt to reduce stack trace to something somewhat more succinct and meaningful?

Comment: Usually folks here want as much detail as possible.  I'll revise my post to also include what's in the DOS window.

Comment: I like the full stack, but it would be nice to be better formatted. What version of Java are you using? You can see this by outputting the result of `./gradlew --version`

Comment: @RobWinch Done!  Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: I don't see the JDK version...can you ensure to include that?

Comment: Its listed as **JVM: 1.7.0**.

Comment: Sorry I missed that..I have answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug that was fixed in JDK 1.7.0_02](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=2213716) and up.

Please [update to the latest JDK 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp) to compile Spring Security. There are also plenty of security fixes that should encourage you to update to the latest JDK 7 as well.

Comment: I'm using build 1.7.0-b147.  I will try upgrading my Java7 installation to the latest version to see if that helps.

Comment: Sounds good...keep in mind the build and the patch version are different numbers. Also note that the build fails for me using 1.7.0_01 with the same error message and using 1.7.0_02 fixed it.

Comment: I upgraded to java version "1.7.0_51" and the build worked.  Thanks!